# wp-signup.php example template

Tags: user-registration, signup, wp-signup

I'm looking for an example wp-signup.php template for which to work with. I've done a search in Google but nothing from the past year comes up.  :/

I've tried:
template-dir/registration/activity.php
template-dir/registration/registration.php
(these are BuddyPress I think)

Comment: You want to create your own signup form?

Comment: Copy the original wp-signup.php file, make the changes you need and use it in your theme as a custom template.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Philip that actually was what I was looking for. Can't believe I overlooked it :)   Please add this as an answer so I can give you the bounty.

Comment: @M.Taylor I'm glad you found an answer in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the original wp-signup.php file,
do the changes you need and use it in your theme as a custom template.

Comment: adding a `wp-signup.php` file in the theme root folder has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ron & Andrea has a plugin plugin that allows you to Style your signup page
See: http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/style-your-signup-page/ for more information.